# Retrofitting opengles 1.0 to 2.0 in Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm currently working on converting Android's San-Angeles example to OpenGL ES 2.0, instead of it's current 1.0 (using my own version of Demo). I am currently getting this error, and I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
06-24 11:02:48.246 2528-2528/com.example.SanAngeles E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.SanAngeles, PID: 2528
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.SanAngeles/com.example.SanAngeles.DemoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.
```

Here is my DemoActivity (Which I assume the issue is in):
package com.example.SanAngeles;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;


public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGLView = new DemoGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("sanangeles");
    }
}

class DemoGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public DemoGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mRenderer = new DemoRenderer();
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            nativeTogglePauseResume();
        }
        return true;
    }


    DemoRenderer mRenderer;

    private static native void nativeTogglePauseResume();
}

class DemoRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        nativeInit();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        //gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        nativeResize(w, h);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        nativeRender();
    }

    private static native void nativeInit();
    private static native void nativeResize(int w, int h);
    private static native void nativeRender();
    private static native void nativeDone();
}
```

Comment: Is this the code for the entire activity? Do you have any code in your onStart() or onResume() methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can peek at the source code for GlSurfaceView [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/opengl/java/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java) (it'll also be somewhere in the sdk installed on your machine) documentation can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html).

The relevant bit of info is that after you call SetRenderer once, you are not allowed to call the following afterwards:

- SetRenderer (a second time)
- setEGLContextFactory
- setEGLWindowSurfaceFactory
- setEGLConfigChooser
- setEGLContextClientVersion

The code you've posted doesn't show that's what you've done, but I think you're probably calling one of these functions in code you haven't posted. The setEGL* functions need to be called before SetRenderer in order to work.